# Lucid nav element gives error about attribute list

Tags: haskell, haskell-lucid

I am currently in the process of rewriting an HTML file in Lucid for use with a Spock web server. However, for some reason this particular snippet gives me an error:

```
sidebar :: Html ()
sidebar = do
  nav_ [id_ "sidebar"] $ do
    div [class_ "sidebar-header"] $
      h3_ "Sidebar"

    div [class_ "list-group"] $ do
      a_ [href_ "#", class_ "menuItem list-group-item rounded-0"] "Item 1"
      a_ [href_ "#", class_ "menuItem list-group-item rounded-0"] "Item 2"
```

Namely, the error is:

```
Couldn't match type `[Attribute]'
               with `HtmlT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()'
  arising from a use of `nav_'
```

I noticed that removing the div and just having the `h3` fixes the problem, but that is not what I want. I did some googling to try to find the issue, but from what I could see the library does not have that many examples online that I could try to look at. Stackoverflow and Reddit searches did not reveal anything either.

This is my first actual project where I have used Lucid, so it is entirely possible that there is an obvious blunder somewhere.

Comment: Did you mean `div_`?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I looked at it on and off probably for an hour or so and somehow I never noticed that. The error was not quite what I would have expected for a typo. Blunder on my part, thank you very much.

Comment: So it was the issue? Neat. I'd never heard of Lucid before.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Lucid uses underscores to avoid conflicts with prelude functions such as div and id. I probably forgot the underscore on a few other occasions, but the compiler warned me since for example nav without an underscore would not be an actual function, but since div is a function I did not get such an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `div` (integer division) instead of `div_` (HTML element).

The type error is slightly bizarre, but arises from how the type checker tries to infer a type for the whole expression.

`class_` has type

```
class_ :: Text -> Attribute
```

Thus `[class_ "list-group"] :: [Attribute]`. That's easy.

`div` has type

```
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

There is an `Integral` constraint, but more importantly, both input types and the result type must be the same.

In an expression like

```
div [class_ "list-group"] $ do
  a_ [href_ "#", class_ "menuItem list-group-item rounded-0"] "Item 1"
  a_ [href_ "#", class_ "menuItem list-group-item rounded-0"] "Item 2"
```

the type checker concludes that `[class_ "list-group"]`, `do ...`, and the whole `div ... ...` expression have the same type.

We know the first type, so we conclude `do { a_ ...; a_ ... } :: [Attribute]` and `div [...] $ do ... :: [Attribute]`.

This use of `div` is the last statement in a `do` block, which means its type is also the type of the whole `do` expression.

I'm a bit fuzzy on the next part, but I think the type checker looks at

```
nav_ :: Term arg result => arg -> result
```

and

```
class Term arg result | result -> arg
```

and the available `Term` instances, and concludes that because the declared result type is `sidebar :: Html ()`, the second argument to `nav_` (the `do` block) must also have type `Html ()`, which is an alias for `HtmlT Identity ()`.

Now we have a conflict: The declared type signature says the second argument of `nav_` must be a `HtmlT Identity ()`, but the inferred type is `[Attribute]`.

At this point the type checker just gives up and reports the confusing problem to the user.